# What is the advantage of using parameter outside of function parameter definition in Scala?

Tags: scala, currying

What is the difference and advantage of using those two ways of writing a function (and how the first way of writing a function is called):

```
def do_something(a:String, b:String)(c:String) :Unit = {}
```

and

```
def do_something(a:String, b:String, c:String) :Unit = {}
```

Comment: Neither of those two are "ways of writing a function". They are both methods, not functions.

Answer (score 0):

It is called ***Currying***, Hier you find a description:
[scala-currying](https://data-flair.training/blogs/scala-currying/)

The **advantage** is that you can partially apply such a function.

Here from the linked article:

> 1. One benefit is that Scala currying makes creating anonymous functions easier.
> 2. Scala Currying also makes it easier to pass around a function as a first-class

Comment: I would add: you can of cause curry things manually with closures, but explicit syntax for currying is better <and explain why it is better>.